# kfp.v2 compile NotImplementedError

Tags: python, vertex, kfp

I'm following this tutorial https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/pipelines/build-pipeline

I'm running this in a Workbench from Vertex IA.

When I run this block of code

```
from kfp.v2 import compiler
compiler.Compiler().compile(pipeline, package_path='image_classif_pipeline.json')
```

I get this error:

```
NotImplementedError: Input argument supports only the following types: PipelineParam, str, int, float, bool, dict, and list. Got: "None".
```

Full error here:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_5793/733682165.py in <module>
      1 from kfp.v2 import compiler
----> 2 compiler.Compiler().compile(pipeline, package_path='image_classif_pipeline.json')

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kfp/v2/compiler/compiler.py in compile(self, pipeline_func, package_path, pipeline_name, pipeline_parameters, type_check)
   1290                 pipeline_func=pipeline_func,
   1291                 pipeline_name=pipeline_name,
-> 1292                 pipeline_parameters_override=pipeline_parameters)
   1293             self._write_pipeline(pipeline_job, package_path)
   1294         finally:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kfp/v2/compiler/compiler.py in _create_pipeline_v2(self, pipeline_func, pipeline_name, pipeline_parameters_override)
   1209 
   1210         with dsl.Pipeline(pipeline_name) as dsl_pipeline:
-> 1211             pipeline_func(*args_list)
   1212 
   1213         if not dsl_pipeline.ops:

/tmp/ipykernel_5793/21893831.py in pipeline(project_id)
     40         validation_fraction_split=0.2,
     41         test_fraction_split=0.2,
---> 42         budget_milli_node_hours=8000,
     43     )
     44 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google_cloud_pipeline_components/aiplatform/automl_training_job/automl_image_training_job/component.yaml in automl_image_training_job(project, display_name, dataset, location, prediction_type, multi_label, model_type, base_model, labels, training_encryption_spec_key_name, model_encryption_spec_key_name, training_fraction_split, validation_fraction_split, test_fraction_split, budget_milli_node_hours, model_display_name, model_labels, disable_early_stopping)
      1 name: automl_image_training_job
----> 2 description: |
      3     Runs the AutoML Image training job and returns a model.
      4     If training on a Vertex AI dataset, you can use one of the following split configurations:
      5         Data fraction splits:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kfp/components/_components.py in create_task_object_from_component_and_pythonic_arguments(pythonic_arguments)
    390             component_spec=component_spec,
    391             arguments=arguments,
--> 392             component_ref=component_ref,
    393         )
    394 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kfp/components/_components.py in _create_task_object_from_component_and_arguments(component_spec, arguments, component_ref, **kwargs)
    328         arguments=arguments,
    329         component_ref=component_ref,
--> 330         **kwargs,
    331     )
    332 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kfp/dsl/_component_bridge.py in _create_container_op_from_component_and_arguments(component_spec, arguments, component_ref)
    317             task.execution_options.caching_strategy.max_cache_staleness = 'P0D'
    318 
--> 319     _attach_v2_specs(task, component_spec, original_arguments)
    320 
    321     return task

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kfp/dsl/_component_bridge.py in _attach_v2_specs(task, component_spec, arguments)
    599             if kfp.COMPILING_FOR_V2:
    600                 raise NotImplementedError(
--> 601                     'Input argument supports only the following types: '
    602                     'PipelineParam, str, int, float, bool, dict, and list. Got: '
    603                     f'"{argument_value}".')

NotImplementedError: Input argument supports only the following types: PipelineParam, str, int, float, bool, dict, and list. Got: "None".
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In the prior pipeline method that you have defined in `/tmp/ipykernel_5793/21893831.py`, remove the `base_model=None` parameter.

Comment: This works for me . But why is there such an error in Google's documentation?